# Inconsistent results using XML layout and SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, layout, camera, surfaceview

I'm using an XML layout to show a custom class which extends SurfaceView along with a single button to the right of it, using the XML code below:

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.my.name.MySurfaceView android:id="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm then using the following code to set the layout for my activity:

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private MySurfaceView mySurfaceView;
    private Button button;

    public MyActivity() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mySurfaceView = (MySurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mySurfaceView.setClick(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The `MySurfaceView` class then extends `SurfaceView` and is setup to show the camera stream.

The problem is, when starting the app, there are often different outcomes. Either:

Both the `Button` and `MySurfaceView` are drawn to the screen at the same time, then the camera stream starts displaying (This is how I'd like it to work every time)

*or*

`MySurfaceView` loads and shows the camera stream for a few seconds, before the `Button` is eventually displayed.

I understand that the `SurfaceView` has to be created and measured etc before the button can be displayed so I should expect a slight delay, but as mentioned above, in some cases the `SurfaceView` displays the camera stream for up to 5 seconds before the button is eventually drawn to the screen.

How I can avoid this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

**EDIT:** 
 It seems as though the `SurfaceView` is not completely finished being created, despite being shown on the screen. I'm using OpenCV to process the camera stream and this seems to still be initialising things after the `SurfaceView` is initially drawn, and so the `Button` is not drawn until all of this is finished.